# How do I determine the radius of convergence of the power series?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Given is $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1-i}$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(0)$.

How do I determine the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z=1+i$ is the only pole - it's simply the distance from $z=0$ to $z=1+i$ which is $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about that, but wasn't sure.

Comment: No worries - please remember to accept the answer if you deem it sufficient.

Comment: I will I have to wait 10 minutes.